# Macro for more than 1 line of code

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm learning the macro system of Common Lisp and suddenly found a problem

```
(defun hello () (format t "hello ~%")) 
(defun world () (format t "world ~%"))
(defmacro call-2-func (func1 func2)
  `(,func1)
  `(,func2))

(macroexpand-1 '(call-2-func hello world)) 
(WORLD) 
T
```

Well. Why can't I generate 2 LoC from only one macro? How can I work around? (<del>progn will not work in a more complicated situation...</del>)

Comment: Hi Mike, could you please give an example where progn wouldn't work. So far I haven't managed to find a situation that some combination of progn or splicing wouldn't solve! Cheers

Comment: @Baggers I redesigned my work and progn would work now.. That's my mistake :-)

Comment: keep in mind that in Lisp there are no LOC source code. We have source forms, which are actually data. A macro does not return text made of lines, but Lisp data forming expressions. A macro has to return one expression as data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your macro needs to return just *one* form that will call both functions.
Instead you are generating two forms (and only the last one is used.)

Try:

```
(defmacro call-2-func (func1 func2)
  `(progn (,func1) (,func2)))
```

or if you do not want to be limited to just 2 functions:

```
(defmacro call-funcs (&rest funcs)
  `(progn ,@(mapcar #'list funcs)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't seem clear in the stuff above, so let me add...  yes you can return 2 lines of code from a macro, but remember functions and macros generally only return 1 value.  You can compute multiple values in function, but it only returns the last value.  This function below only returns value-2 (it still computes value-1, it does nothing with value-1).

```
(defun myfun () (compute-value-1) (compute-value-2))
```

If you want to return 2 values you can either wrap them in a list (or other structure), or you can use #'values to return more than one value.

In this case, your macro can only return one statement, unless you wrap multiple values in a list or use #'values.  What it returns has to be proper lisp code too, and usually that is done with a PROGN

```
(defmacro call-2-func (func1 func2) `(PROGN (,func1) (,func2)))
```

If you used

```
(defmacro call-2-func (func1 func2) `(,func1) `(,func2))
```

Then your macro computes 2 values, but it only returns the last one. (as you see in your macroexpand above)

You can see this easily with a defun that computes 2 values but only returns the last one.

```
(defun myname () 1 2)
```

Using VALUES gets a little weird.

```
(defmacro tttt () '(values (one) (one)))
(tttt)
1
1
```