# Generate code in macro lisp

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I would like to generate code: `(nth 0 x) (nth 1 x) ... (nth n x)`
where `x` is just some variable name, and `n` is some number.

I'm trying do this in a following way:

```
(defmacro gen(n)
    (loop for i from 1 to n do
    `(nth i x))
)
```

Checking how it expands by:
`(print (macroexpand-1 '(gen 5)))`

Console output is: `NIL`. How to do it properly?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583663/how-do-i-write-a-macro-that-will-repeat-a-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macro for more than 1 line of code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930091/macro-for-more-than-1-line-of-code)

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace [`do`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ae.htm) with [`collect`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ac.htm) in your [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_loop.htm).

Note however that your macro captures the variable `x` from the calling environment.

Generally speaking, "macros are advanced material", if you are not comfortable with `loop`, you probably should not be writing them.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what the value of the following code is:

```
(loop for i from 1 to 5
   do `(nth ,i x))
```

Since there's no collection happening, the return value of the `loop` is nil. If we change `do` to `collect`:

```
(loop for i from 1 to 5
  collect `(nth ,i x))
```

We see that we are getting somewhere. However, the resulting list is not actually valid Common Lisp code (and relies on there being a variable `x` in the environment where the macro is used).

It is not clear what you want to do with these (just run them? they're side-effect free, so just wrapping this in a `progn` feels somewhat useless), but you need to either cons a `progn`, `list` or similar to the front of the list of lists to make it into valid code.

```
(defmacro gen (n &key (var 'x) (accumulator 'list))
  (cons accumulator
    (loop for i from 1 to n
      collect `(nth ,i ,var))))
```

This eventually gives us this macro that seems to actually do something approaching "valid".